# Arabic culture datetime parsing not returning expected values

Tags: c#, datetime, culture, tryparse, arabic-support

I'm not sure if the problem i'm having is because of a lack of understanding of how the datetime's work in the Umm al-Qura calendar works, or if it's a bug.

Basically i'm working on writing a test to ensure that an internal utility class properly parses values regardless of the current culture.

In the code below, the goal is to have **dt1** equal to **dt2**.

```
    public void ArabicTesting()
    {
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("ar");

        // Initialize a new datetime (04/01/2048 06:21:01 AM)
        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2048, 4, 1, 6, 21, 1);

        // Convert the datetime to a string using arabic cultureinfo
        // string ends up being "17/06/70 06:21:01 ص,"
        string dt2_string = $"{dt1.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)} {dt1.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern)}";

        // Parse the string
        DateTime dt2;
        DateTime.TryParse(dt2_string, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt2);
    }
```

The problem is that **DateTime.TryParse** is parsing the datetime as a string into a datetime that appears the same, but has different values than what is expected.

Here are a couple of screenshots of what is happening:

[image: dt1]
[image: dt2]

If you look at both **dt1** and **dt2** preview values, they appear the same "17/06/70 06:21:01 ص,", however, the actual values of the objects are completely different.

Does anybody know if this is an MS bug, or is it because I am not passing the correct string value into the **DateTime.TryParse** method?

Comment: What happens if you use a `LongDatePattern` instead of a `ShortDatePattern`?  `string dt2_string = $"{dt1.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern)} {dt1.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern)}";`

Comment: @Igor that did work for this scenario - thank you.  I'm still a little concerned, it seems like a problem to me that the default ToString method of a DateTime returns identical values for different dates.

It must not be standard to use a short date pattern in arabic cultures if that can happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure the full date is captured try using `LongDatePattern` instead of `ShortDatePattern`.

```
string dt2_string = $"{dt1.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern)} {dt1.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern)}";
```

The results of the 2 could be different based on this as the `ShortDatePattern` could omit a datepart that might then have a default value be wrongly assumed in the parse method such as the full year (example). What part is or is not assumed depends on the culture used and some cultures probably work either way while others will have problems (like Arabic).

To better debug why this happened in this particular case you could compare the 2 strings from `dt1.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern)` and `dt1.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)` and see what part of the date could be substituted with a default value from the current date/time at run time.

Comment: It seems counter-intuitive that there would exist a pattern for writing dates that can refer to more than one date, although i guess those exist in english culture as well (e.g. 06/27/16)

With that being the case, I can easily see why this problem is happening now.  It's definitely good to know, so thank you for helping with that!